# Batch file to take backup of the files

Tags: batch-file

I am new to this , Actually my requirement is to take backup of some XML file from one machine to another machine .So my senario would be when i click on the batch file it will create a new folder on the second server (name of the folder should be date and time )and under this folder it paste all the copied files .
I need to create a new folder every time as i am doing version control.

Thanks
VG

Comment: Which part do you have trouble doing? :)

Answer (score 1):

The batch file is very simple

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "copydest=%date%_%time%"
for %%i in (/ - : .) do call set "copydest=%%copydest:%%~s=%%
xcopy "c:\path\to\your\datafiles\*.xml" "c:\parent\%copydest%\"
```

which should copy the `.xml` files from the directory `c:\path\to\your\datafiles\` to a new directory under `c:\parent\`which has the date/time as its name.

The precise structure of that date/time depends on your settings. If you don't tell us what your settings are, we'd have to write a book about all of the possible combinations - not going to do that.

The `for %%i...` line does the removal of the common date/time separators; of these `:` and `/` are the important ones since they are invalid in a filename.

Comment: Thanks Magoo for the quick responce .With the help of your code plus with some modification I am able to create and paste data in another folder.But now I want to take it one step ahead as I want to take backup for only those files which are recently been modified or created.

Comment: Open another question if you want to change it.  They are free.  Check the help on this page and take the `Tour` also.